# Unity - Get Local Mouse Position from the center of the Gameobject clicked on

Tags: unity-game-engine, raycasting, mouse-position

I want to get the mouse clicked position from the center of the gameobject, say a Sphere of Scale(1, 1, 1), for instance. If I click on the center of the sphere it should return the x component as zero, on clicking to the extreme left of the sphere, it should return -0.5 as the x component of the vector3 and 0.5 on clicking the extreme right of the sphere. The below code helps me achieve this when at origin. However, there is one constraint for it. The Sphere has to be positioned at (0, anything, anything) (as I am concerned with the x axis).
Any help on how can I achieve this regardless of the Sphere position?

```
bool isGameOver = false;
float pointX;

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    if(!isGameOver){
        RaycastHit hit;
        if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)){
            Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
            if(Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit)){
                if(hit.transform.tag =="Ball"){
                    pointX = transform.InverseTransformPoint(hit.point).x;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you using a perspective camera or ortographic?
If you are using perspective and you move your game object to right, you cant hit on the 0,5 of the right side. Because is behide your visible part of ball.
Only can do it with orto camera

Comment: This makes sense. I was using the Perspective camera. How can I make it work in perspective? Any idea!

Comment: Though it didn't solve my issue.. It helped me to solve it. The rotation has to do with the variable result that I was getting..

Answer (score 0):

Your code is ok for this.
If you need the object position only need to add the transform.localposition to your pointX.

```
pointX = transform.localPosition.x + transform.InverseTransformPoint(hit.point).x;
```

Comment: My code is not OK for different position of the sphere. It only works when the sphere is at origin or if the x axis value is 0. However, it gives incorrect values when the x axis position of sphere is other than 0.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to rotate your gameobject looking for the camera and you get now the right x coordinate you need.

```
void Update () {
    if(!isGameOver)
    {
        Vector3 offset =  transform.position - Camera.main.transform.position;
        transform.LookAt(transform.position + offset);
        RaycastHit hit;
        if(Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0)){
            Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
            if(Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit)){
                if(hit.transform.tag =="Ball")
                {

                    pointX = hit.transform.InverseTransformPoint(hit.point);
                    Debug.Log ("X:" + pointX.ToString());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```